# Ransack search form for nested model in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I want to search and return an index of Users based on their Profile data using Ransack in my Rails 3 app. In the docs it mentions nested attributes but since I'm a beginner I'm not sure how to use the helpers to accomplish what I want.

The [ransack docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ransack/0.5.8/frames) recommend the following:

**`users_controller.rb`:**

```
def index
  @q = User.search(params[:q])
  @users = @q.result(:distinct => true)
end

def search
  index
  render :index
end
```

**`routes.rb`:**

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'users#search', :via => [:get, :post], :as => :search
  end
end
```

**`app/views/users/index.html.erb`:**

```
<%= search_form_for @q, :url => search_users_path,
                    :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

In the form I've tried to weave in the profile by using:

```
<%= current_user.profile.high_school %>
<%= f.text_field :profile_high_school_cont %>
```

Doing this doesn't work, however. The results show nothing when I search for a field belonging to at least one User's profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this does work. I had a `f.check_box` that was messing things up.